# ¿Hay algún modo de hacer esto solo con una consulta?

Tags: php

En esta parde del código me gustaría saber si hay algún modo de hacer una única consulta a la base de datos.Cuando realizo la primera consulta para saber si existe un elemento con el id que le paso por get uso execute() y luego cuento las columnas que devuelve para saber si existe o no, luego viene la condicional en la cual le digo: si resultado1 es menos o igual a 0 entonces que lleve a la página central ya que no existe el producto por el contrario si es mayor a 0 entonces que convierta la consulta en un fetch. Pero la cosa es que si dejo solamente $fila =$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); me toma la variable resultado2 como si fuera un booleano pienso que es por el contador fetchColumn() para resolver este problema entonces hice otra consulta, haciendo esa consulta ya funciona bien, pero me gustaría saber por qué pasa eso y si hay algún modo de solo usar una consulta. Gracias.

```js
<?php
  include("./php/conexion.php");
  if ( isset($_GET['id'])){
    $resultado = $con ->prepare("select * from productos where id=".$_GET['id']);
      $resultado->execute();
      $resultado1=$resultado->fetchColumn();
      if ($resultado1<=0) {
        header("Location:index4.php");
      }else {
        $resultado2=$con ->prepare("select * from productos where id=".$_GET['id']);
          $resultado2->execute();
          $fila =$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Cambia la condición: `if($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { /* ejecutar código necesario */ } else { header('Location: index4.php'); exit; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacerse solo con la primera consulta, el chequeo puede ser simplemente verificar que hayan datos al llamar a `fetch()`. Solo cuando hay datos se obtiene un array con resultados.

```
<?php
  include("./php/conexion.php");
  if ( isset($_GET['id'])){
      $resultado = $con ->prepare("select * from productos where id=".$_GET['id']);
      $resultado->execute();
      $fila =$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if (!$fila) {
        header("Location:index4.php");
        exit;
      }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Solo falta [`exit;`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) después de redirigir, porque `header()` solo envía el encabezado al navegador, pero el _script_ continúa ejecutándose.

Comment: @Triby corregido, gracias

Comment: Si se trata únicamente de saber si hay registros lo más apropiado sería una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productos ...`  y luego usar `fetchColumn()` para verificar si el resultado es mayor a cero. El problema aquí, en términos de **optimización**, es que estás haciendo un `fetch` de varias columnas para nada. Además, una consulta `COUNT(*)` debería ser más rápida.